# Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found on WP log this error, how can I fix it?

Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Qapla_Woocommerce has a deprecated constructor in...

line error is:

class Qapla_Woocommerce{

the code is:

global $Qapla_Woocommerce;
$Qapla_Woocommerce = new Qapla_Woocommerce();

class Qapla_Woocommerce{

```
var $version = '1.1.3';

function Qapla_Woocommerce() {
    /* Languages */
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( &$this, 'load_plugin_textdomain' ) );

    /* Meta box in admon order page */
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( &$this, 'woocommerce_metaboxes' ) );

    /* Send shipment to pushTrack API */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', array( &$this, 'woocommerce_process_shop_ordermeta' ), 10, 3 );

    /* Send order to pushOrder API */
    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', array( &$this, 'custom_process_order'));

    /* Add a tracking section to customer order page */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( &$this, 'track_page_shipping_details' ) );

    /* Add a tracking section to transactional emails */
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( &$this, 'email_shipping_details' ), 10, 3 );

    /* Admin section */
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'qapla_admin_menu'));
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'qapla_register_settings'));

    /* Add a column to admin order list */
    add_action( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', array( &$this, 'add_shipping_column'));
    add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', array( &$this, 'add_shipping_column_details'));

    /* Update order from Qapla' */
    add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'qapla_update'));
}
```

Comment: try renaming Qapla_Woocommerce method to __construct

Comment: i tried to change: class Qapla_Woocommerce{ to __construct but web site page is blank.

Comment: You should check the php version that your code was meant to run in

Comment: PHP version is 7.2.6

Comment: Check the version that code was written for. Not the version that you are currently using. To my knowledge,  this kind of constructor was deprecated on 7